# restrict access to a website using Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, authentication

What do I need to do in Windows Server 2008 to restrict access to a website (or directory in the website) to only certain users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enabled Basic Authentication and disabled Anonymous Authentication.  I created a user with read and write permissions on the folder.  The created user's credentials are what I use to view the website.

Answer (score 1):

NTFS permissions will take precedence over the site/virtual directory's permissions if they're more restrictive:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739391(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

IIS can restrict websites to an IP address or range of addresses, this is useful for making a website visible to an entire office (eg, a development website restricted to your own, and your clients office IP ranges)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730889%28WS.10%29.aspx

This isn't really authentication as such, but is often quicker and easier to setup, but it's less secure (IP's can be spoofed).